# BASH: Variables in a function piped to dialog are lost

Tags: linux, bash, dialog, subshell, command-substitution

I have a script with a function which does some stuff and sets some variables to be used later in the script. This function is also echoing progress (echo 10, echo 20 etc.) and is piped to a "dialog --gauge" to display a progress bar. After the function completes and dialog exits, all variables set in the function are lost.

For simplification, it is the following logic:

**myScript.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

myFunction() {
    _var1=1
    _var2=2
    _var3=3
    #Do stuff..
    echo 0
    sleep 1
    echo 25
    sleep 1
    echo 50
    sleep 1
    echo 75
    sleep 1
    echo 100
    sleep 1
}

myFunction | dialog --backtitle "Backtitle" --title "Title" --gauge "\\nWait while stuff is being done...\\n\\nProgress:" 10 60

# Or
# dialog --backtitle "Backtitle" --title "Title" --gauge "\\nWait while stuff is being done...\\n\\nProgress:" 10 60 < <(myFunction)

echo -e "Var 1: $_var1" # Is empty
echo -e "Var 2: $_var2" # Is empty
echo -e "Var 3: $_var3" # Is empty

exit 0;
```

Any ideas on how to implement this without losing the variables?

Thank you!

```
./myScript.sh
Var 1: 
Var 2: 
Var 3:
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to @chepner, the solution proposed in the first comment worked:
`myFunction > >(dialog --backtitle "Backtitle" --title "Title" --gauge "\\nWait while stuff is being done...\\n\\nProgress:" 10 60)`

Comment: You need `myFunction` to execute in the current shell, not in a subshell/subprocess created by a pipeline or process substitution. Can you run `dialog` in the process substitution instead? `myFunction > >(dialog ...)`

Comment: Better yet, can you restructure the code so that `myFunction` does not need to both set global variables and provide input to `dialog`?

Comment: @chepner Thank you for the comments. Unfortunately the first one does not work, it just opens dialog and does not continue (neither with echoing progress, is stuck at 0). The second one is a possible workaround. I can reconstruct the code to set the variables outside of the function. But I am curious if this can be done from within. Thank you!

Comment: `bash` only has an option to allow the *last* component of a pipeline execute in the current shell. If neither of the options I mentioned work, I think you're out of luck. (Whatever `dialog`, via `ncurses`, does to write to standard output, the process substitution appears to disturb.)

Comment: @chepner Disregard my above comment please. I did it fast and made a typo. It seems that "`myFunction > >(dialog ...)`" is working on this script. I'll test it on the actual script as well. Thanks!

Comment: You can't have the cake and eat it. You need to set the variables in your current process, if you want to use them three. One possility would be to have one function `set_vars`, which sets the variables, and you invoke this function from within `myFunction` *and* from your main script. Another possibility would be to not use a pipe, but direct the output of `myFunction` to a temporary file, which you then use as stdin to `dialog`.

Comment: Really? I finally noticed I have `dialog` installed and tried it, and did not see the dialog box at all.

Comment: @chepner Yes, it works with `myFunction > >(dialog ...)`, but for some reason it is breaking my terminal's encoding, and it is not usable after the script exits. But the variables are not lost. I'll drill down to it further!

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks! Yes, I will change the way the variables are set if it can't be done from this function.

Comment: BTW, I find your approach a bit odd anyway: You use `--gauge`, which is usually used for displaying a progress bar. But the process running `myFunction`  writes to stdout bufferd, so I would expect that `dialog` will most likely see all the output from the function at once, and not piecewise as you would expect.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, it's working. The encoding thing most likely has something to do with how dialog draws the TUI. After dialog I did a `clear` before echoing the variables and everything is displayed normally. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1934428 It sees it piecewise though. The progress echoing is not being done statically like in the simplified script in the OP. In this function there are a few thousand operations to be done (create files, set variables, add content to files etc.). The total operations to be done is being calculated in the function at first, then when they are actually being made (using loops within the function), a variable is being incremented and along with the value of that variable and the known total number of operations, the percentage is calculated and echoed with each iteration.

Comment: @user1934428 ... and the progress bar in dialog --gauge is being filled as expected, piece by piece.